# WPF not responding checkbox in observable collection c#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkboxlist

I have this code where i have a code with observable collection (type Herarhy Model) with check boxes.
on some event I what set the check box to disabled.

The problem : 
 - When I run over the code with debbuger I see that it does changed to disable but I don't see the change on the interface.

- I think that it's some thing in observable collection. 
  also when i remove the item from the observable collection and put it back again it does updating.

  ```
  <ListView.View>
     <GridView  AllowsColumnReorder="False">
         <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header=" ">
              <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsBulkUpdatedChecked}"  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsBulkUpdatedEnabled}"/>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="175"  Header="Project Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="120"  Header="Code" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Code}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="120"  Header="Step" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectedStep}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="150"  Header="Version Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActiveVersion}"/>
  </GridView>
  ```

  ```
  private ObservableCollection<HierarchyModel> _ProjectsFamily = new ObservableCollection<HierarchyModel>();
          public ObservableCollection<HierarchyModel> ProjectsFamily
          {
              get
              {
                  return _ProjectsFamily;
              }
              set
              {
                  _ProjectsFamily = value;
                  RaisePropertyChanged("ProjectsFamily");
              }

          }




          public bool IsBulkUpdatedChecked
          {
              get
              {
                  return Hierarchy.IsBulkUpdatedChecked;
              }
              set
              {
                  Hierarchy.IsBulkUpdatedChecked = value;
                  RaisePropertyChanged("IsBulkUpdatedChecked");
              }
          }


          public bool IsBulkUpdatedEnabled
          {
              get
              {
                  return Hierarchy.IsBulkUpdatedEnabled;
              }
              set
              {
                  Hierarchy.IsBulkUpdatedEnabled = value;
                  RaisePropertyChanged("IsBulkUpdatedEnabled");
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: What is Hierarchy? You're using it in the getter/setters of the property. Also, try setting the BindingMode to the CheckBoxe's IsChecked to TwoWay

Comment: I think that it's some thing in observable collection. also when i remove the item from the observable collection and put it back again it does updating.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an error in the Output Window in Visual Studio that tells you something like this:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsBulkUpdatedChecked' property not found on 'object' ''ListViewItem' (Name='This')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsBulkUpdatedChecked; DataItem='ListViewItem' (Name='This'); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Object')...

That is because the `ListViewItem` class doesn't have an `IsBulkUpdatedChecked` property. Instead of using that `Binding Path`, you should use one that points to where you have *actually* defined that property. I can't tell you where that is because you didn't bother to show us. I can only guess that it is in the object set as the `Window.DataContext` property value... in that case, try this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsBulkUpdatedChecked, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" IsEnabled="{Binding 
    DataContext.IsBulkUpdatedChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```